# chrome - ssl certificate does not show up after importing from from jks keystore

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

I have a jks (`keystore.jks`) that contains both the servers CA certificate (alias `serverca`) and my certificate (alias `mycert`) that was signed by that CA. I exported `mycert` to a `.cer` file via

`keytool.exe -export -alias mycert -storepass mypass -file mycert.cer -keystore keystore.jks`

I take that newly created `mycert.cer` file and import it into chrome

(Settings -> Advanced -> Manage certificates -> Personal -> Import...)

I get an "import successful" message. But after I restarted Chrome I cannot see the `mycert.cer` file in the chrome certificates. And I also cannot connect to the server. I also added the CA certificate to chrome, still same issue.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: When you say "my certificate". Do you mean your certificate to be used for client-certificate authentication? Is that private key also in this keystore?

Answer (score 3):

You have to let Chrome automatically decide in what certificate archive the certificate should be saved. You probably picked Personal and got a message along the lines of "Certificate imported successfully" even though it didn't.

Comment: been googling for hours, thank you!